# Generating javascript file per each user

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a small application similar to this http://www.hellobar.com/

Essentially what the application needs to do is the following:

- allows the user to signup
- for each user generate a *whatever-app-clientId.js* file that the user needs to deploy on their pages
- allows the user to customise the javascript widget (styling for example)
  Is not clear to me what is the best way to generate this file, the only idea I came up with is to have a template js file that gets updated every time a user signs up or edits the settings and then pushed to a CDN.
  What is the best way to generate such JS?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like XSLT might be a good choice for this. It's excellent for templating and transformation.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipmultxsl/) on how to generate files with XSLT.